# Will Wayland ever support graphical sudo?

Tags: sudo, su, wayland

On the X desktop, I ocassionally used `gksudo` or just `sudo somegui` to launch GUI applications as another user, including root. I recently discovered that this is not possible on contemporary (early 2018) Wayland desktops. All applications must launch as the current desktop user, and are limited to the privileges of that user.

Is this a permanent feature of Wayland (there by design), or is su-type usage an enhancement that has not yet been implemented?

*I'm looking for a documented statement (roadmap, design page...), not preference or opinion.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this a permanent feature of Wayland (there by design)

No. This has nothing to do with the wayland protocol. It is rather a question of environment setup.

Wayland uses a socket, its name is stored in `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`. It is located in `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` that is normally set up for user access only. But root can access it, too. (Some applications also regard `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` which can have values `wayland` or `x11` to decide whether to use X or Wayland.)

`sudo` deletes most environment variables including `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`.

You can run wayland applications as root with:

```
sudo env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR WAYLAND_SOCKET=$WAYLAND_SOCKET waylandapplication
```

or shorter with `-EH` to preserve almost all environment variables (but setting `HOME` to `/root`). This will include `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` for Xwayland access, too:

```
sudo -EH application
```

Though, if the application running as root writes anything in `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, it can cause file permission issues for user applications.

However, running graphical applications as root in wayland is much less a security issue than it is in X11.

To avoid using X11 accidently, you can run without `DISPLAY`:

```
sudo -EH env DISPLAY=  waylandapplication
```

---

> I'm looking for a documented statement (roadmap, design page...), not preference or opinion.

The [Wayland documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/) mentions `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, but I do not find anything about `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. Though, all wayland compositors including the reference implementation `weston` depend on `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

If `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` would be at another location, it would not be a problem to run applications from arbitrary users on the same wayland display. But [`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` ist specified](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) to be restricted on the logged-in user and should contain user related sockets:

> $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR defines the base directory relative to which user-specific non-essential runtime files and other file objects (such as sockets, named pipes, ...) should be stored. The directory MUST be owned by the user, and he MUST be the only one having read and write access to it. Its Unix access mode MUST be 0700.

The issues with running another user or root on wayland are rather related to the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` specification than to wayland itself. If you specify a custom `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in `/tmp` with arbitrary access (thus breaking its specification), all users can use the wayland display.

There is some hope for the future not to need `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, but it depends on the implementation: [Wayland docu chap.4](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch04.html):

> Beginning in Wayland 1.15, implementations can optionally support server socket endpoints located at arbitrary locations in the filesystem by setting WAYLAND_DISPLAY to the absolute path at which the server endpoint listens.

Comment: `sudo -EH` to keep environment but reset HOME?

Comment: @muru thanks, I've added your suggestion to the answer. I was not aware of `-H`.

Comment: `sudo -EH env DISPLAY=  waylandapplication` works to launch apps as `root`, but `sudo -u normal_user -EH env DISPLAY=  waylandapplication` fails to launch the app under a non-root user.

Comment: I've tried all of these with synaptic, and still get `Probably you're running Synaptic on Wayland with root permission.`; My next step is probably to purge wayland entirely from my system, and avoid installing distributions that use wayland until this issue is fixed.

Comment: Edit: none of these worked for me. If you're in the same boat, please try answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596468/134513

Comment: @MRule AFAIK synaptic does not support Wayland but needs X11. Only few applications support Wayland as of today. As a rule of thumb, GTK3 and QT5 applications should work.

Comment: @Maximko `normal_user` does not have access to `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` of another user.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote `ego` (Alter Ego) for this use case. It's not a GUI app, but you can launch GUI apps from the console as another user, it automatically handles xhost and Wayland and PulseAudio socket sharing: https://github.com/intgr/ego

The trick is using Posix ACLs to grant access to the Wayland/PulseAudio sockets to another user, and setting environment variables so applications of the target user know how to connect to it.

If you run into problems, please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Now, this is a wonderful tool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two fairly easy workarounds. The examples below start synaptic but any other command should do.

1. Using ssh X-Forwarding to the root user (you may have to enable root login in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or configure key auth):

```
$ ssh -Y root@:: synaptic
```

2. Using socat & sudo, as proposed by [bober on RedHat Bug #1274451](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451#c43). The example below assumes we're on display #0 and #1 is free...

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 & sudo DISPLAY=:1 synaptic
```

I believe either way the workaround is to have a user-owned process to connect to X11 socket and provide tunneling .

Comment: Thank you! Option 2 is the ***ONLY*** solution that's worked for me so far; It seems to me entirely unacceptable that Ubuntu would ship a "stable" release where running GUI apps with sudo requires hacks like this.

Comment: I've created a little shell script named `wlsudo` with this command; It seems to work similarly to `gksudo`: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
`socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 & sudo DISPLAY=:1 $1`; Solves everything.

Comment: This does not answer the question but shows a way to access Xwayland as root.

Answer (score 2):

This extends [Thomas Guyot-Sionnest's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596468/134513).

I feel like this deserves its own answer, since it cleaned up so many issues for me. Create a shell script called `wlsudo` with the following contents:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 & sudo DISPLAY=:1 "$@"
```

Save it in a directory on your `$PATH`, and give it executable permissions (`chmod +x ./wlsudo`).
You should then be able to launch GUI apps using `wlsudo` in place of `sudo` in Wayland, e.g. `wlsudo synaptic` *just works*.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not answering your question directly, I think there are people who may have ended up here because of the same problem.

This is a script that I have made is a workaround for people who need to run graphical application (like **Gedit**, **Synaptic** or **GParted**) as root via **sudo** in a **Wayland** session:

https://gist.github.com/wachambo/bd22e12db2d5a46dc109bd0d553733be

Imported here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Enable root access to x-windows system.
#
# Motivation: Trying to run a graphical application as root via su, sudo in a 
# Wayland session (e.g. GParted or Gedit), will fail. Apps which use polkit to
# request administrator permissions for just certain operations and only when 
# needed are not affected (they are not started as root right away). 
# [1] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451
#
# Based on a Reddit comment.
# [2] https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/5eb633/solution_running_graphical_app_with_sudo_in/

if (( $# != 1 )); then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters."
    echo
    echo "Usage: wsudo [command]"
    exit 1
fi

for cmd in sudo xhost; do
    if ! type -P $cmd &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$cmd it's not installed. Aborting." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

xhost +SI:localuser:root
sudo $1
#disable root access after application terminates
xhost -SI:localuser:root
#print access status to allow verification that root access was removed
xhost
```

Comment: this is great, but I think better posed as a separate Q&A, with a link to this question, it will then come up as a related question - I'm also happy to link to the new question

Comment: This is a great hint, but it does not work on SSH connections - only on the local console.

Comment: @Kalle With ssh X forwarding you can just run the command - in fact you can run them "locally" too by ssh'ing to the root user; i.e. `ssh -Y root@::`.

Comment: Sorry, but it is out of question to enable ssh:ing into system as root user. This is for security reasons - commands executed throuh sudo can be limited, and they leave a trace on logs.