# Why can I not open gparted from the command line?

Tags: x11, gparted

I seem to be unable to start gparted from the command line. I am using Trisquel 8 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) with LXDE. If I try to open it, I get the following error and nothing happens:

```
$ sudo gparted

(gpartedbin:7820): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

However, it seems to open fine from the graphical application menu.

I searched a bit online and one recommendation was to try:

```
xhost +localhost
```

However, that didn't help. Apparently, it seems there can be an issue with opening gtk applications from the command line as root in Wayland; however, I am using X11. This is just on a local laptop - no ssh-ing or remote systems involved.

It seems strange, because I have always been able to open gparted from the command line in the past. I have also tried re-installing gparted and that didn't seem to help.

**Update:**

Following meuh's suggestions in the comments, I added `DISPLAY=:0` to the /etc/environment file, so it should be passed when using sudo. However, I am still experiencing an error, but it has now changed:

```
$ sudo gparted
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:5549): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

It seems that the DISPLAY variable is now being passed, but I'm not sure what that 'no protocol' message means.

Comment: Looks like the environment variable DISPLAY is not set (it should be seen following the error message "...display:"). Try `DISPLAY=:0 sudo gparted` or if that fails, `sudo sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 exec gparted'`

Comment: Hmm. The DISPLAY variable was already set to ':0' and it wasn't working. However, the method of using `sh` and `exec` did work. Strange.

Comment: The `/etc/sudoers` file can configure what variables are passed through the sudo command. Look for `env_keep` in the file. Try `sudo -ll` to list the current setting for you.

Comment: @meuh I added `DISPLAY=:0` to /etc/environment, so that variable should be passed with sudo; however, I am still getting the error, but it has changed. I will update my question with the details.

Comment: Does it work without `sudo` from the terminal? I get the same error as you with `sudo`, but without it I get an authentication pop up to type root password and everything works properly. I'm still trying to understand this myself.

Comment: @PaulH. No, if I type `gparted` without sudo on the command line, I get an error saying: 'Root privileges are required for running gparted'. mviereck's answer below of passing XAUTHORITY to sudo did work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access X you need environment variables `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`. Depending on setup, sudo may delete them. You can check that with `sudo env` to see the environment variables.

To preserve your users environment, you can use `sudo -E`. That has the pitfall setting `HOME` to your users home, and config files may get wrong file permissions. However, to avoid that, `sudo -H` sets `HOME` to `/root`.

Combine this for gparted:

```
sudo -EH gparted
```

Only desired variables can be set with:

```
sudo env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gparted
```

---

Error messages:

`cannot open display:` means `DISPLAY` is empty or does not exist.

`no protocol specified` means `DISPLAY`is set and vaild, but `XAUTHORITY` pointing to authentication cookie is not set or the cookie is invalid. Alternativly, `xhost +SI:localuser:root` allows root temporary access to X until logout.

---

Similar goes for Wayland access with `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` and `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. Wayland root access issues can be solved with `sudo -EH`, too. For detail and a pitfall with `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` see [Will Wayland ever support graphical sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422040/will-wayland-ever-support-graphical-sudo/423287#423287)

Comment: Great. I added XAUTHORITY to the list of variables being passed to sudo and that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is `kdesudo`, `gsudo`, and some other `sudo`s that solve this.

Here is one, I hacked together (not security audited/tested).

```
#/bin/bash

inner() {
    su  - "$user" -c "xauth list" |
        grep "$(echo "$display" |
                cut -d ':' -f 2 |
                cut -d '.' -f 1 |
                sed -e s/^/:/ ) " |
        xargs -n 3 xauth add &&
        "$@"
}

if [ "$1" = "---innermode" ]
then
    shift
    user="$1"
    display="$2"
    shift 2
    inner "$@"
else
    self="$0"
    sudo "${self}" ---innermode "$USER" "$DISPLAY" "$@"
fi
```